# Beamer boxes and marginal

Tags: beamer

I was asked to make a LaTeX document visually like our PPT template, see picture. I have figured out for example `\definecolor{tuniviolet}{RGB}{78,0,142}`, but how to make white left and top margin? Also, how to add a date and page number to a given location in the footer? Just saying `\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\hfill\insertframenumber}` puts the number in the bottom right corner with zero marginal.

[image: Our PPT template]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use the sidebar outer theme and adjust the width and height to fit your template (this also has a build in mechanism to place a logo at the top left)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\definecolor{tuniviolet}{RGB}{78,0,142}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=tuniviolet}

\useoutertheme[width=0.3cm,height=0.7cm]{sidebar}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{sidebar left}{bg=white}
\logo{\makebox[\beamersidebarwidth][l]{\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=0.7cm]{example-image-duck}}}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this helps. Now, how to get the logo wholly seen? Now it only shows up partially.

Comment: @JoriMäntysalo `\logo{\makebox[\beamersidebarwidth][l]{\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=0.7cm]{example-image-duck}}}`